# Can I convert a .rda file to a pandas dataframe in python without using R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, feather

I'm practicing my Python, specifically my numpy and pandas. I have some data (not mine) in .rda format that I want to import into python as a dataframe. However I don't use R, so I'm wondering if I can do this without fiddling around with the base file. From what I've seen on the site, feather has been recommended and so I've tried the following:

```
import feather
path = 'pathtomydata.rda'
df = feather.read_dataframe(path)
```

But this produces a "ArrowInvalid: Not a feather file" error, which makes it sound like I have to dig into the .rda file and make it into a .fea file first, which I'd rather not do as I imagine I'd have to install R. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this helps https://pypi.org/project/rdata/ or this https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pyreadr, which does not require R to be installed:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('pathtomydata.rda')

# done! let's see what we got
print(result.keys()) # let's check what objects we got
df1 = result["df1"] # extract the pandas data frame for object df1
```

More information here:

https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr